# How do I get all of the keys in this JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$mystring = '{
    "display_name": "Silverware",
    "user": "joesmith",
    "id": 27,
    "field_name": "Age",
    "sort_order": 1,
    "required": 0,
    "view_type": "text"
}';
```

I'd like a PHP array with all of the keys from the code above. Whats the most efficient way?

Comment: Basically use `json_decode` and then loop over it with a `foreach`

Comment: He specifically mentioned "array" so I would use `json_decode($mystring, true)` (the second parameter makes the output array instead of object).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> get all of the keys in this JSON with PHP

Short solution using `json_decode` and `array_keys` functions:

```
$keys = array_keys(json_decode($mystring, true));
```